# Static Sql connection in Azure function 2.0

Tags: azure-functions

Azure Function Eventhub trigger with SQL connection is causing an issue because of too many calls so i want use static connection but it;s not working

Tried the below code approach and it's not working

```cs
 _config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(context.FunctionAppDirectory)
                    .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                    .Build();

                connection.ConnectionString = _config.GetConnectionString("SqlConnection");
                await connection.OpenAsync();
```

Comment: What's the meaning of not working? Did you get any error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the SQL connection string with [local.settings.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local#local-settings-file), it's only used by Functions tools when running locally. These settings are not migrated automatically when the project is published to Azure.

So you should set the connection string in the Application Settings. As for the detailed information, you could refer to this tutorial:[Set the connection string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scenario-database-table-cleanup#set-the-connection-string).

And this is the sample code about how to use SQL with Function:

```cs
[FunctionName("DatabaseCleanup")]
public static async Task Run([TimerTrigger("*/15 * * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
{
    // Get the connection string from app settings and use it to create a connection.
    var str = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("sqldb_connection");
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(str))
    {
        conn.OpenAsync();
        var text = "UPDATE SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader " +
                "SET [Status] = 5  WHERE ShipDate < GetDate();";

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(text, conn))
        {
            // Execute the command and log the # rows affected.
            var rows = await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
            log.LogInformation($"{rows} rows were updated");
        }
    }
}
```